# Can you learn the Primal Savagery cantrip via the Spell Sniper feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, cantrips

The third benefit of the [Spell Sniper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/spell-sniper) feat says:

> You learn one cantrip that requires an attack roll. Choose the cantrip from the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list. Your spellcasting ability for this cantrip depends on the spell list you chose from: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock; Wisdom for cleric or druid; or Intelligence for wizard.

Since the [*Primal Savagery*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/primal-savagery) cantrip makes an attack roll, can it be learned this way?

The spell has a range of "Self", and uses a melee spell attack rather than a ranged one, so I'm unsure if it can be learned using the spell.

Comment: Is there a reason you think this might not work?

Comment: Because the range is self and does not benefit from this feat.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. I've edited the reason you're unsure into the post itself; please check to make sure I've maintained your intent.

Answer (score 10):

## Yes!

Spell Sniper gives several benefits, including allowing you to learn a spell meeting three criteria:

- Is a cantrip
- Requires an attack roll
- Is on the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list

*Primal Savagery* is a druid cantrip that requires an attack roll. It meets all three of the criteria for Spell Sniper.

It does not make a ranged spell attack, and doubling a spell with a range of self will have no effect, so the other two benefits of Spell Sniper will not affect this particular cantrip. This does not stop you from picking it as the spell you learn from the last benefit.